# How load images in widget in listView item via glide (or other)

Tags: android, image, android-widget, android-glide, remoteview

I have widget with `ListView`. And I try load image in list item into `ImageView`

```
var uri = Uri.Parse(item.UrlPreviewImage);
var widgetTarget = new AppWidgetTarget(_context, Resource.Id.imageView_widgetListItemRss_rssIcon, itemView, _widgetId);
Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Glide.With(_context.ApplicationContext)
             .AsBitmap()
             .Load(uri)
             .Into(widgetTarget);
    });
```

and it works, but some strange. It removes from screen other elements and make the background transparent.

[image]

But must work like this (only with icons in left):

[image]

What I must do? Thanks

P.S. Code in C# but in Kotlin or Java will also will useful

More code:

```
public RemoteViews GetViewAt(int position)
{
    var itemView = new RemoteViews(_context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget_list_item_rss);

    var item = _list[position];

    var subTitle = item.UpdateTime == null
        ? Strings.RssFeedItemNotUpdated
        : $"{Strings.RssFeedItemUpdated} {item.UpdateTime.Value.ToShortGeneralLocaleString()}";
    var countMessages = item.CountNewMessages.ToString();

    itemView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.textView_widgetListItemRss_title, item.Name);
    itemView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.textView_widgetListItemRss_subtitle, subTitle);
    itemView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.textView_widgetListItemRss_rssCount, countMessages);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.UrlPreviewImage))
    {
        var uri = Uri.Parse(item.UrlPreviewImage);
        var widgetTarget = new AppWidgetTarget(_context, Resource.Id.imageView_widgetListItemRss_rssIcon, itemView, _widgetId);

        Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Glide.With(_context.ApplicationContext)
                .AsBitmap()
                .Load(uri)
                .Into(widgetTarget);
        });
    }

    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: What is the need of Glide.AsBitmap()? Try to remove it.

Comment: @NickBapu And I get ```java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.Bitmap.``` Glide.AsBitmap just cast

Answer (score 2):

For Glide ver.4 I use:

```
FutureTarget<Bitmap> futureTarget = Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("picture URL")
            .submit(250, 250);
    try {
        row.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.yourImageViewInItemView, futureTarget.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolve it with Picasso

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.UrlPreviewImage))
{
    try
    {
        var picture = Picasso.With(_context).Load(item.UrlPreviewImage).Get();
        itemView.SetImageViewBitmap(Resource.Id.imageView_widgetListItemRss_rssIcon, picture);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```